# How to adjust the title in the header of my blogspot blog?

Tags: css, blogger, blogspot

I have one blog called https://toadynewselite.blogspot.com but there is some problem in space, in header there is unknown space that make blog ugly.

[image: space above the title in header]

I used custom template in blogspot. The title doesn't fit correctly in header. There is an empty space before the title in the header of the blog. Also the title is partially hidden in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CSS

```
.header-header {
    height: auto;
}
.header-logo {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: this works well, this solves the problem but the spaces still exist. i want the title to fit perfect in the header. i want to remove the space completely above and below the title

Answer (score 0):

go to `.header-header` and replace CSS code by:

```
.header-header{
    background-color: #99C9F9;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
```

and `.header-logo` replace CSS code by:

```
.header-logo{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: this works well, this solves the problem but the spaces still exist. i want the title to fit perfect in the header. i want to remove the space completely above and below the title.